# Calling asynchronous functions from an array

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

`PromisesInSeries` function that takes an array of asynchronous functions and sequentially (the next one starts when the previous one has finished) calls them, passing the result of calling the previous function as arguments

```
function promisesInSeries(asyncFns) {
    let result;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        for(const fn of asyncFns){
            resolve(fn)
            .then(data => fn(data))
        }
    })
}
```

I only get the results of the first function. How to call all functions from an array and, as a result, return the last value?

Comment: I am not sure, but *if this were possible*, I would think that you need to return an array of promises, not a promise with an array of calls.  This is because *each* of the functions is async, so *each* will need an associated promise.

Comment: use promise all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `async`/`await` you could [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the `fns` array:

```
function promisesInSeries(fns) {
  return fns.reduce((promise, fn) => promise.then(fn), Promise.resolve());
}
```

The first `fn` will receive the value `undefined`, after that each return value is passed to the next function.

If you want to have some initial value, you can provide it by changing `Promise.resolve()` to `Promise.resolve(initialData)`. Where `initialData` could be a static value or a value passed through function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use async-await, this is way easier:

```js
async function promisesInSeries(asyncFns) {
    let result;
    for (const fn of asyncFns) {
      result = await fn(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to pass data from one function to another.

Comment: @Evert impossible without async-await?

Comment: I tried to rewrite it with what I *think* you want. It's certainly possible without async/await but I'm sharing this as a valid solution that's likely the most readable.